# Get a module's version number in Orchard CMS 1.8+ using code

Tags: orchardcms

On occasion, I like to log a module's version number.  How do I get a module's version number within code (programmatically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way you request `IOrchardServices` in your controller's constructor, you can request `IExtensionManager`.  Then, using the `GetExtension` method with the name of the module (as indicated in *module.txt* id), it returns an `ExtensionDescriptor` that exposes the `Version` property, among other useful properties.

You can see an example of using `IExtensionManager` in the [RecipeHarvester](https://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Recipes/Services/RecipeHarvester.cs) source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a module from anywhere in the code, you would need to initialize an ExtensionManager first. To do that, you will need the current workContext. This is the way I did that.

```
public class Extensioner
{
    public IExtensionManager _manager { get; set; }

    public Extensioner()
    {            
        var httpContextAccessor = System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(
            typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as IHttpContextAccessor;

        var workContext = WorkContextExtensions.GetWorkContext(httpContextAccessor.Current().Request.RequestContext);

        _manager = workContext.Resolve<IExtensionManager>();

    }

    public string getModuleVersion(string moduleName)
    {
        var _ver = "unknown";
        if (_manager != null)
        {
            _ver = _manager.GetExtension(moduleName).Version;
        }

        return _ver;
    }
}
```

The page which showed me the way:

https://disqus.com/home/discussion/skywalkersoftwaredevelopment/orchard_webapi_global_actionfilters_and_dependency_injection/

And some theory: 
https://orcharddojo.net/orchard-resources/Library/Wiki/WorkContext